# Global Actions Issue

Tags: global-actions

We are using Lightning in my Salesforce instance, and I am trying to add "New Account" and "New Contact" to my overall Global Actions (+) option.  They are not showing there, even though I have modified both my layouts and updated the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions like so:

[image: Publisher Actions]

When I go to the Global Actions (+) the New Account, New Contact option are not there and do not show up on any other objects.

Any reason why?

FYI - my org have 3 different record types for accounts and contacts.  (I have made custom actions for them and still nothing).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Trailhead unit [Understanding How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions):

> The Global Actions menu displays a subset of global actions from the
> Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions section of the global
> publisher layout. Specifically, these types of global actions are
> supported in the menu: Log a Call and Create a Record quick actions
> that point to the Events, Notes, and Tasks objects.

So, anything that isn't related to activities or notes is being filtered out.

Comment: Thanks!!! I read that but wanted to make sure!

Comment: I have been researching but there is a clear cut way to remove the Global Action (+) from the homepage in Lightning without impacting Salesforce1, correct?